# How to block specific IP address in Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, ip-address, ibm-cloud

I want to block some IP addresses from accessing my website, which is hosted over IBM Bluemix with Node.js runtime.

However, I don't know how I can block the list of IP addresses there. The only solution I came up with is not configure on Bluemix but write it on my Node.js app, such like:

```
function(req, res) {
    req.ip // use this property to diverge, depending on the user's IP address
}
```

However, I would like to get it done on Bluemix part, not on my node.js app. Is it feasible to do it?

For your information, this was not feasible in Heroku, another PaaS. Maybe is it feasible in AWS, IaaS, right?

Comment: I am afraid it's not possible yet. Bluemix offer some authentication services, but it's not the same thing. :-( https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/15453/can-i-create-private-spaces-on-bluemix/?smartspace=bluemix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking specific IP addresses is not possible as part of your described scenario. This is related to any PaaS as they are dealing with apps and services, not the network infrastructure itself.

There are slightly more options when operating on Bluemix Dedicated or Bluemix Local. The Secure Gateway service has options for blacklisting IP addresses, but that feature is used to secure your on-prem resources, not the app.

Comment: I see. What is the *on-prem* resources? And then is the IaaS like AWS feasible to configure the blocked list of IP addresses, right?

Comment: "on-prem" is short for on-premises, basically in your local data center (or your computer). IBM Bluemix also offers to block IP adresses if you use the IaaS componentes like Docker container or virtual servers. And the foundation for Bluemix is Softlayer which offers these capabilities, too.